# scrollview didnt work

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I add in an interface builder a scroll view to the view, and included in this scrollview some labels and a table view.
The problem however is that the stroller doesn't work and by so, it doesn't scroll.

The first thing I want to know if I can put table view in a scroll view with some labels? And if yes, what do I need to add?

Comment: Maybe some code for us to look at?

Comment: i didn't do it with code,i use the interface builder to add this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an IBOutlet for your scroll view, then in your view did load method put

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put UITableView in UIScrollView because UITableView is a UIScrollView subclass. It will cause gesture misunderstanding and your app will not be working properly. I recommend reading UITableView Class Reference.

Comment: so if i want to make table view to a view and put in the head some labels and image,there is any way to do it?

Comment: You can create UIView with your labels and images and then set _tableView.tableHeaderView = yourViewWithImagesAndLabels_ in your viewController.

Comment: Apple documentation allowing to create nested UIScrollViews. Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html)

Answer (score 1):

`UIScrollView` will not scrolling if `scrollView.contentSize` smaller than `scrollView.frame`. Did you set contentSize of your `UIScrollView`?